# How to retain messages in mqtt if the mosquitto broker goes down?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have a scenario wherein the MQTT client publishes a message with a topic . Post this I bring down my mosquitto broker (by killing the process) . When I restart my broker and try consuming the message with the topic , the message is not available . Is there any way I can consume the message which was published before the broker is restarted ?

Note : This is possible if RabbitMQ is used as the messages are stored in the queue . I want to implement the same using MQTT-Mosquitto.

Answer (score 10):

If you enable *persistence* and specify a directory in your mosquitto.conf file then retained messages will be saved to disk and restored when the broker is restarted.

e.g.

```
persistence true
persistence_location /path/to/store/data/
```

Also look at the `autosave_interval` and `autosave_on_changes` options in the [docs](http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html)

Comment: Thanks you for the reply !!! But should the persistence_location be relative to the location where mosquitto is installed ? I tried giving the location D:/  .  But this does'nt seem to work

Comment: Note that a trailing `/` is required on `persistence_location`

Comment: I have created a folder in D drive mqtt. I have the following in my conf file - persistence_location D:/mqtt/  . Should'nt this be fine ? This does'nt seem to work

Comment: The mosquitto.db is not created after publishing the message . Is there anything that I am missing ?

Comment: @hardillb - Yes I did . I have the following in my conf file -   autosave_interval 5                                                                persistence true                                                                         persistence_file mosquitto.db                                                persistence_location D:/mqtt/                                                                  I have set the auto interval time to 5 so the the mosquitto write to the disk every 5 seconds

Comment: same issue to me,

Comment: the issues mentionned above might be due to incorrect file permission. Mosquitto is run a the "mosquitto" group. I suggest the following configuration entries `persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/` (and also `autosave_interval 5` but only for debugging, remove it afterwards )

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment the following three options in the `mosquitto.conf` file (`dir/to/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf`):

```
persistence true 
persistence_file mosquitto.db
persistence_location /path/to/store/data/
```

For me it was not enough to just enable the two options stated in the other answer to this question.

Regarding the `persistence_location` please read the given comment in *mosquitto.conf*. However, you can just specify an absolute path, but you need to make sure, that the user who runs mosquitto (maybe root or not in your case) has the permission to write into this directory.

If you running mosquitto in a docker container based on the image *eclipse-mosquitto:latest*, your container should have mounted a docker volume, where you can point `persistence_location` to.
Check with `docker volume ls` if you have the volume *mosquitto_data*. In that case, you could set `persistence_location mosquitto_data/`.
With `docker inspect mosquitto_data` you get info about the docker volume, including the *Mountpoint* on the host system.
In this scenario you can also change your *mosquitto.conf* from the host system, it is in the docker volume *mosquitto_conf*